# Как закрасить произвольную фигуру в Pillow Python

Tags: python, pillow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я создаю текстовую рпг игру и в ней хочу реализовать шкалу опыта, по идеи у меня будет что-то типо такой рамки, потом будет рисовать линию по середине поперёк, потому что допустим у моего персонажа 50% опыта и всё что мне нужно это закрасить левую часть этой рамки, есть ли какой метод, способ как закрасить произвольную фигуру с помощью pillow?
(Если кому интересно как я рисую изображение в консоли могу ответить)

Comment: Сложите сложную фигуру из нескольких и меняйте цвет по одной.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floodfill-image-using-python-pillow/

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо, то что нужно было)